# Exporting OBJ file from Blender, why are normals for each face vertex the same?

Tags: blender, wavefront

For example I created a sphere in blender, and exported the obj file. I was noticing some issues in my shader, because all the vertex normals for a face are the same. And can see it directly in the .obj file itself, such as portion below, see that for the first face, all the verticies are using normal index 1. I would expect they should all be different since it is a sphere, and are curving. Thanks, also this is in Blender 3.1

```
f 10/10/1 9/9/1 22/22/1 23/23/1
f 6/6/2 5/5/2 15/15/2 16/16/2
f 480/526/3 10/10/3 23/23/3 24/24/3
f 7/7/4 6/6/4 16/16/4 17/17/4
f 481/527/5 480/526/5 24/24/5 25/25/5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and I needed to add shading to the object in blender. Edit Mode->Select all vertices, and select smooth shading.